# AttributeError: module 'pygmo' has no attribute 'spea2'

Tags: python, pygmo

`Pygmo 2.1` haven't `SPEA2` Algorithm implemented yet?

I'm asking because `SPEA2` looks fully implemented on `Pygmo` documentation

`nsga2` algorithm it's ok.

Steps to reproduce error:

```
import pygmo as pg <br/>
algo = pg.algorithm(pg.spea2(archive_size = 0))
```

I expect get no errors, but i am getting

```
AttributeError: module 'pygmo' has no attribute 'spea2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the example [documentation](https://esa.github.io/pygmo/tutorials/spea_ii_nsga_ii_and_ns_pso.html), I think this could work:

```
from PyGMO import *
alg = algorithm.spea2(archive_size = 0)
```

You're trying to access `spea2` from the base module whereas it is a part of the algorithms sub-module.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this code doesn't work, same error:
AttributeError: type object 'algorithm' has no attribute 'spea2'
I had read entire documentation, but i think it's not implemented yet.

Comment: I really doubt that. I can see it in the [documentation](https://esa.github.io/pygmo/documentation/algorithms.html#PyGMO.algorithm.spea2) that it has indeed been implemented